# x-text not working when variables updated

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I just tried Alpine.js recently but I think it too complicated or I miss understand it

Here is my code:

```html
<div x-data="wordcount()" class="wordcount-container">
<p x-text="wc"> </p>
</div>
<textarea id="writing" @keyup="wordcount().updateWordCount()" ></textarea>
```

```js
    let wordcount_writing = 0;
    function wordcount(){
        return {
            wc: wordcount_writing,
            updateWordCount(){
                this.wc = document.getElementById("writing").value.length;
                wordcount_writing = this.wc;
            }
        }
    }
```

I had tried to check wordcount_writing variable when I'm typing on textarea by console log it's work fine but x-text don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Alpine.js' data model you don't have to do any of this to get the text length. You can define the model data `writing`, bind it to the `textarea` with [`x-model`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/model#textarea-inputs), then you can access its length via `writing.length`. This variable is reactive, so you don't have to manually update the length.

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ writing: '' }">
  <p x-text="`Text length: ${writing.length}`"></p>
  <textarea x-model="writing"></textarea>
</div>
```